# divide Stocks-Data wit Earnigs per share - Data to get the P/E ratio

Tags: python, division, finance, jupyter-lab

I have this Data(from Refinitive Workspace) df_sxde(this are close prices from different stocks) and df_eps(this are the earnigs per share)

i want to divide df_sxde by df_eps so i can get my P/E ratio->(df_sxde/df_eps=P/E ratio)

```
df_sxde = ek.get_data(instruments=['SASY.PA', 'ESLX.PA', 'SHLG.DE', 'BAYGn.DE',
       'PHG.AS', 'FREG.DE', 'FMEG.DE', 'MRCG.DE', 'EUFI.PA', 'UCB.BR'],
       fields=['TR.PriceClose(SDate=2021-05-31,Curn=EUR)'])

df_eps = ek.get_data(instruments=['SASY.PA', 'ESLX.PA', 'SHLG.DE', 'BAYGn.DE',
     'PHG.AS', 'FREG.DE', 'FMEG.DE', 'MRCG.DE', 'EUFI.PA', 'UCB.BR'],
      fields=['TR.BasicEpsExclExtraItems(SDate=0CY,Period=FY0,Curn=EUR)'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DataFrames have matching shapes you can simply do:

```
df_pe = df_sxde / df_eps
```